# Cómo hacer este UPDATE en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un **UPDATE** sencillo

```
UPDATE  tblmvto_lotes SET codtipo = 2 , rendimiento = 0  WHERE codlote > 18271
```

Lo que necesito es que cada vez que yo ejecute el **UPDATE** este aumente, es decir este **UPDATE** actualiza los campos **codtipo, rendimiento** del lote **18271** la próxima vez que se vuelva a ejecutar no actualice el **18271** si no el **18272** y así sucesivamente de uno en uno.

me pueden ayudar con alguna idea o de que otra manera lo puedo hacer

Comment: Por qué lo haces de esa forma? por qué no envías el `codlote` como parámetro?

Comment: Porque esto se va estar ejecutando frecuentemente y automáticamente, el solo tendría que llenar ese parámetro, que el mismo vaya aumentando

Comment: Puedes crear una tabla y leer de ahí el valor de `codlote` e incrementarlo en cada llamada.

Comment: tienes un link para mirar el ejemplo o algo que me guié

Comment: Deberías de mejorar tú escenario, porque no se puede deducir, muchas cosas importantes por el mero hecho de tener una update. ¿Se debe de modificar el lote siempre que se haga una update a esa tabla?, ¿Solo para esas columnas?, ¿Te planteas aplicar un trigger?¿Es aceptable que se salten números de lote?¿Puede tener alta concurrencia esa tabla?¿Solo hay un registro, o por el contrario, cada "producto" puede tener un lote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create table ContadorLote(
  codlote int;
)
--inicializar el valor del código a modificar
insert into ContadorLote values(18271);


-- aquí empieza el código de la actualización

--recuperar el valor del lote a actualizar y guardarlo en una variable
DECLARE @codlote INT = (SELECT top 1 codlote from ContadorLote) ;

UPDATE  tblmvto_lotes SET codtipo = 2 , rendimiento = 0  WHERE codlote = @codlote

--actualizar el campo `codlote` con el valor del siguiente código a actualizar
UPDATE ContadorLote set codlote = @codlote + 1
```

Comment: Si realizas esto así y la tabla tiene alta concurrencia, puedes generar saltos, o repeticiones del lote. La select del declare @codlote debe de ir entre paréntesis. Una opción podría ser utilizar un nivel de transacion serializable, para que contadorLote este bloqueada desde la select hast su propia update, de manera que otra lectura no genere el mismo Codlote https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Muchas gracias justo lo que necesitaba